# What is the specific package for this module 'utils'?

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-b085e7ba8941>", line 1, in <module>
    from utils import log_progress

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

What is the pip command to install this module?

Comment: what is the pip command to install this module?

Comment: You seem to be reading *"Hands-On Transfer Learning with Python"* - does that come with any installation instructions/code snippets?

Comment: Yes you are right. Actually I did not find any instruction to install this package.

Answer (score 0):

the utils module in book, "Hands-On Transfer Learning with Python", is not a python pakages that need to install using pip command.

this is a custom module in utils.py python files on github repo. so you should clone or download utils.py file

https://github.com/dipanjanS/hands-on-transfer-learning-with-python/tree/master/notebooks/Ch05%20-%20Unleash%20the%20Power%20of%20Transfer%20Learning

Comment: additionally, usually wirte down utility functions, such like log_progress, check_files, import data ... etc, in file name "utils.py". So, in many notebook, using command "from utils import <function name>"